# How to make pug(jade) process no value attribute

Tags: pug, vuejs2, vue-loader

For example,

```
div(attr)
```

will become

```
<div attr="attr"></div>
```

If I want

```
<div attr>,/div>
```

what should I do? I use pug with vue-loader, it would be better offering exact configuration.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in blank string as any attribute's value, then in browser `inspect element` that attribute is rendered as `attr` only not `attr=""`.

```
input(type="checkbox", checked, attr="")
label Testing
```

Here is [codepen link](https://codepen.io/mikedeveloper/pen/JNaabz)